# Optimal way to clean Lightning port?

Tags: iphone

Every few months or so, my iPhone 6S becomes unable to charge via the lightning port without jiggling the cable. I am able to fix this problem by using a paper clip to clean pocket lint out of the port. A surprising amount always comes out!

However, I'm always a little nervous about damaging my phone while cleaning the port. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Apple doesn't have any official, public-facing support documents for cleaning Lightning ports, you may be straying into opinion territory.

Users have reportedly successfully and safely used paperclips, plastic or wooden toothpicks, compressed air, vacuum cleaners with a hose, and even tightly rolled sticky tape. Paperclips and other metal objects reportedly have the ability to damage your iPhone's Lightning port pins and some methods are allegedly better than others.

Whatever you use is up to you, provided you can maneuver the object in a way that you don't damage the port's pins.

(Sources include [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/4zwze8/psa_clean_your_lightning_port/) and [Stack Exchange](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/how-to-clean-the-charging-port-of-iphone-6), but answers are anecdotal.)

Comment: Agree - don’t use metal... the air plastic and wood options sound better.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific about an easily available, non-metallic, item, I ended up cutting a Q-Tip on a shallow slant(you need a sharp knife, razor blade to do this).  Now it fits into the port and it’s soft enough not to damage the contacts overmuch.

Wriggle it back and forth and keep in mind the geometry of the contacts (you want to clean the “wall and ceiling” of the port).

```
O=====\
```

Bit of blasted air to finish since I had some.  But probably wasn’t essential.